# Change the address of a variable passed as a void* function parameter

Tags: c

I have a callback function `void string_cb(char* data, size_t size, void* str)` which uses a prototype `void callback_decl (char* data, size_t size, void* ret_val)` where the last parameter is a return value. Because my callback needs to allocate a memory for a string with `malloc()`, I need to change the address of the `void* str` to allocated memory block. Is it possible to assign a new address to str without changing the callback prototype?

Comment: Can you give more details? I assume you're passing this callback to some library? If yes, to what library and to what function in it?

Comment: It depends on what is actually passed in that argument. If the caller passes in a `char **` then newly allocated memory can be returned. You'll have to provide more context.

Comment: provide code of callback_decl and string_cb, only the part you're using for callback and also clear up the memory issue? It's hard to understand what you;re trying to do.

Comment: That clearly won't work. As I said, if the caller passes in a double pointer then you can do something like: `char **ret = ret_ptr; *ret = malloc();`. So there needs to be an understanding between the caller and the callback function. Otherwise it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can... but not with your `string_cb` declaration. If you want to be able to return the address of a newly allocated array, you need a `char **` as the last parameter:

```
void slbin_handler_nstring(char* data, size_t data_size, void* ret_ptr) {
    char** ptr = (char **) ret_ptr;
    *ptr = malloc(data_size);
    if (!(*ptr)) return;
    memcpy(*ptr, data, data_size);
}
```

If should be called that way:

```
char *ptr;
slbin_handler_nstring(data, data_size, &ptr) ;
```

Comment: @SergerBallesta, yes, I tried to call puts(ptr) after the callback method, got segfault.

Comment: @iTs.SL4y3R: I tested it after your comment, and it did segfaulted but it was caused by a number of typos in my code. I have fixed them, and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With the signature `void callback_decl (char* data, size_t size, void* ret_val)`, the caller is solely responsible for providing allocated memory. It is not possible for the invoked callback to allocate memory internally.

If you think about it for a moment, that's actually to prefer, as the caller knows a lot better where the memory should be allocated (heap or stack), and has full control over the entire life time of the string.

Usually this pattern is combined with a special value for `ret_val` which indicates **provided bufferis too small** so that the caller can issue the callback again, but with a larger buffer.